# JsonUtility returning an empty list

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

Im trying to store some items as a JSON file and fetch them during runtime. Im trying to create a List of the ItemDescription objects. But the List is returning empty. I am not getting any error but when I put a breakpoint I saw that the `listOfItems` was empty after `listOfItems = JsonUtility.FromJson<ItemList>(jsonString);`.

```
 using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.IO;

    public class ItemDictionary : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Dictionary<ushort, ItemDescription> itemDictionary = new Dictionary<ushort, ItemDescription>();
        private ItemList listOfItems;

        private string path;

        void Start()
        {
            path = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/itemDescription.json";
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(path);
                listOfItems = JsonUtility.FromJson<ItemList>(jsonString);

                //Populate dictionary via JSON
                foreach (ItemDescription item in listOfItems.itemList)
                {
                    Debug.Log(item.itemName);
                    //itemDictionary.Add(item.id, item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("ITEMDESCRIPTION FILE CANNOT BE FOUNDD");
            }

        }
    }


    [System.Serializable]
    public class ItemList
    {
        public List<ItemDescription> itemList;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class ItemDescription
    {
        public string itemName;
        public ushort id;
        public string description;
        public ushort stack;
        public uint cost;
    }
```

JSON FILE

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "itemName": "Regular Dirt",
      "id": 1,
      "description": "Dirty dirt",
      "stack": 500,
      "cost": 0
    },
    {
      "itemName": "Regular Stone",
      "id": 2,
      "description": "It's hard",
      "stack": 500,
      "cost": 0
    },
    {
      "itemName": "Regular Sand",
      "id": 4,
      "description": "It gets everywhere.",
      "stack": 500,
      "cost": 0 
    }
  ]
}
```

I have already tried chaging all the types to strings, renaming the `ItemDescription` class to `Items`,`ItemList` class to `Items`.

Comment: Are your classes decorated with "Serializable" ? (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html)

Comment: @RyanWilson Ya. I have them at the bottom of the `ItemDictionary` class. They are both `Serializable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing to this.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ItemList
{
    public List<ItemDescription> Items;
}
```

Comment: Wow! That fixed it! Is it because I defined "Items" inside the JSON file? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @D.Haritheesan No, it's because you declared it as `private` "Fields that have unsupported types, as well as `private` fields or fields marked with the `NonSerialized` attribute, will be ignored." - Straight from the documentation I linked to in the comments.

Comment: Yea the naming does matter. I always just run my json through this to get me a starting template and go from there. http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @RyanWilson Hey sorry man didnt see the link. Also I made all the fields in the subclasses public. Are you talking about `private ItemList listOfItems;`?

Comment: @RyanWilson No, actually it is because OP's field name `itemList` didn't match the one given in the JSON which is `Itmes` ;)